# How can one open Excel (the program, not a file) from a perl program?

Tags: windows, perl, excel

I currently have a perl program in Windows that creates and populates an excel file via Spreadsheet::WriteExcel, but I'd like to have that file opened as my program closes. I tried googling for information, but all I found was how to open and read excel files within perl. Would anyone be able to help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend this:

```
`your_file.xls`;
```

It just executes a system command.  Assuming Excel files are set to default open with Excel, this will work (adding the full path to the file may or may not be necessary, depending on your setup).

Other options:

```
system("your_file.xls");
`C:\\Program Files\\...\\excel.exe your_file.xls`;
system("C:\\Program Files\\...\\excel.exe your_file.xls");
```

Comment: I'm assuming I need to hardcode the full path of the excel.exe file into my program? I'm a bit wary of doing that, as I'll need to distribute my program and I don't want a custom installation of excel to mess everything up.

EDIT: This was made before your edit. I tried it now, with just the address to the file itself and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, turns out the system call delays the termination of my program. Although if I manually terminate my program, excel is still up, which is what I want (and if I close the excel program, my program terminates normally). I checked system() at perldoc, but it doesn't say anything about terminating the perl program after calling the subroutine. Is there any other way to stop my program, or is it something that I just have to live with?

Comment: If anyone needs to know how to start a process and not wait for it to end in order to stop their program, I hope this helps: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=410066

Comment: @GabeC. Use the [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) function in Perl to execute a command without waiting … Your program will terminate at that point however. `exec "C:/path/to/excel.exe", "your_file.xls" or die "Can't open Excel"` (please use normal slashes, Windows understands them as well)
 — 
Backticks should be used when you are interested in the *output* of the program, the `system` function when you need the *return value* and `exec` when you want to continue your process with another program.

Comment: @amon, thanks for the additional information.  I tested out `exec`, and that will also work on simply the path to the Excel file; no need to specify the path to excel.exe.  One problem: unlike the other two options, `exec` seems to have trouble with paths that include spaces.  I had pass in quotes to make it work, like this: `exec '"c:/folder with spaces/file.xls"';`

Comment: @dan111: please don't recommend backticks for circumstances that they weren't designed for. The big difference between `system()` and backticks is in what they return. `system()` returns the return code from the called program, backticks return the output that the called program writes to STDOUT. In this case you don't want the contents of STDOUT, so you shouldn't use backticks. Actually, as others have pointed out, in this case `exec()` is exactly what you want.

Comment: @dan1111 All of Perls external program invocation methods like exec do *shell expansion*, like ending an argument when a space is encountered. Read the documentation at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html to understand how to overcome this: Using an argument list instead of a single string and providing the program name can help: eg `exec {"excel"} "c:/path with spaces/to/file.xls";`

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Win32::OLE](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32%3a%3aOLE) for this.  OLE is the Office extensions that you can use to perform tasks with the applications.  This example should work (I haven't tested it):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
my $excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
  || Win32::OLE->new( 'Excel.Application', 'Quit' );
$excel->{Visible} = 1;
```

If you end up going down this route, [here's a reference to the Excel 2007 commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb149081%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: I checked out Win32::OLE, but the one problem I had was that the excel program closed as soon as my program closed. dan1111's answer allows the excel program to stay open even though my perl program terminates, and it's also simpler, but thanks for your input!

Answer (score -1):

The following works for me.  It does not require using any additional module(s).

```
system "start excel $file";
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the exec command in Perl like this:

```
my $excel_file = "file.xlsx";
exec "cmd", "/c", "start", $excel_file;
```

This will open the **default** program in your system to open xlsx files.
I like this option because if the user does not have excel installed, only libreoffice (for example), the system will open the file with libreoffice.