# How to open xlsx file withough hanging a perl process

Tags: windows, perl

I am trying to open a xlsx file in a Perl script with the command : 
`system("path_to_file\\file.xlsx");`
The file is opened but it keeps the perl process hanged until I close the .xlsx file. How can I avoid that?

The file `file.xlsx` is created in the perl script. At the end of the execution I want it to be displayed to the user (like you would manually open it) and it works but it keeps the perl process hanging until i close it.

Comment: The `system` is for executing commands, running programs.  To open a file you use [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).  See [perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html). But for Excel files you may want to use one of a number of modules.

Comment: @zdim I know how to open files for reading, writing. I wasn't explicit enough. I will edit the question

Comment: `system(1, $file)` will run the command and immediately return without waiting for the child to finish.

Comment: OK, I see.  Still, `system` executes commands, and your example "runs" an Excel file! I am surprised that it works.  You want to run an application which will display the file, like office or such.  (Hopefully something far ligther.) So you want to do it in a _non-blocking_ way.  See the comment by [tanktalus](http://stackoverflow.com/users/23512/tanktalus) for Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one open Excel (the program, not a file) from a perl program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971146/how-can-one-open-excel-the-program-not-a-file-from-a-perl-program)

Comment: @ChankeyPathak the accepted answer there is the opposite of what the OP here wants I believe.

Comment: @zdim: Windows uses the file type to determine what program to use to open it. So entering the name of a .xlsx file on the command line will cause it to be opened with Excel, in just the same way that entering `main.pl` will cause the file to be opened and run using `perl.exe`.

Comment: @Tanktalus: It's important to say that that will work only on Windows.

Comment: @Borodin  I suspected that, thank you for explaining it.  Is that then also an accepted (or preferred?) way to open application-specific files via `system` on Windows?

Comment: @zdim: Most often you will want to do something useful with the file. You can use `Win32::OLE` to open and control the appropriate application, or in some cases, such as this one, there are reverse-engineered libraries that allow you to do a lot without using the application at all.

Comment: @Tanktalus thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Tanktalus you can post your comment as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, `system(1, $cmd)` will run the command and immediately return without waiting for the child to finish.  See [perlport](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlport#system).

On Unix, `fork` and `exec` will work to this end.